# Is it possible to sync data at specific intervals in react native using AWS Amplify DataStore

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-datastore

I'm using AWS Amplify DataStore in my react native application. It seems as if at every moment DataStore is trying to sync data, this has however slowed down the performance of my application. I wanted to know if there's a way to sync data only at specific times?

I've made some research and found about fullSyncInterval but I can't understand anything